# Get objects between a number in array in UnderscoreJs

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm looking for a way in Underscore.js to find two numbers that lay between a number in an array.

Number cannot be < 5 && > 20 or any of the numbers in the list.

I have a working Javascript version

```js
var data = [
        { key: 5 },
        { key: 10 },
        { key: 15 },
        { key: 20 }
    ];

    function getBetween(xTest, xyLists) {
        for (var ic = 0; ic < xyLists.length - 1; ic++) {
            if (xyLists[ic].key <= xTest &&
                xyLists[ic + 1].key >= xTest)
                return [xyLists[ic], xyLists[ic + 1]];
        };
    }

    console.log(getBetween(9, data)); //expect 5,10
    console.log(getBetween(16, data)); //expect 15,20
```

I have been trying something like this

```
 _.first(_.filter(xyLists, 
   function (item) { return item.key >= xTest; }), 2);
```

Comment: With `filter` and `map`. [`data.map(obj => obj.key).filter(num => num > 5 && num < 20)`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/72vdf9Lt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array is already sorted by the key value, then you need to compare the previous or the next value also like

```js
var data = [{
  key: 5
}, {
  key: 10
}, {
  key: 15
}, {
  key: 20
}];

function getBetween(xTest, xyLists) {
  return _.map(_.filter(xyLists, (item, idx, arr) => (item.key <= xTest && (arr[idx + 1] || {}).key >= xTest) || (item.key >= xTest && (arr[idx - 1] || {}).key <= xTest)), item => item.key)

  //return xyLists.filter((item, idx, arr) => (item.key <= xTest && (arr[idx + 1] || {}).key >= xTest) || (item.key >= xTest && (arr[idx - 1] || {}).key <= xTest)).map(item => item.key)
}

snippet.log(JSON.stringify(getBetween(9, data))); //expect 5,10
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(getBetween(16, data))); //expect 15,20
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. Works fine in Chrome, but somehow not in IE

Comment: @bluee it might be because of the [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)